# GKSConnSettings message in xcode console

Tags: ios, xcode

Got this message suddenly in my app  -

```
   <Info>: 22:20:44.800330 com.apple.AVConference: GKSConnSettings: set server: {

        "gk-cdx" = "17.173.254.218:4398";
        "gk-commnat-cohort" = "17.173.254.220:16386";
        "gk-commnat-main0" = "17.173.254.219:16384";
        "gk-commnat-main1" = "17.173.254.219:16385";
     }
```

Where does it comes from?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6.0 + this log will show up as soon as your localPlayer is authenticated, i.e. set

```
[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error) {
        if (viewController != NULL) {
            // present the viewController now
        } else if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
            NSLog(@"Already authenticated");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not authenticated, disable GameCenter");
        }
    };
```

and if necessary present the viewController to log into GameCenter

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct tells me it could be related to your environment. Are you working from a virtual machine by chance? This happened to be my case.

Comment: I'm a little slow in response. My apologies. It looks like this is related to the Game Center. Dismiss the previous comment. I'm working with XCode 4.5. 

Are you trying to access Game Center through the SandBox? If so, try this: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/168811?tstart=0